# Window focus is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, window, focus

When I click on the Notebook button I want it to open notebook.html, if I click it a second time I want Notebook.html to come in to focus WITHOUT refreshing.  (the user updates Notebook.html, refreshing loses the data they update.)

This partially works however it DOES refresh the page and I lose any data that has been added.

```
<script>
function openNotebook() {
    window.open('notebook.html', "notebook","width=800, height=600, resizable=yes, top=50, left=10").focus();
}
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return openNotebook()">Notebook</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

- test if you already opened it
- return false to stop a possible form submission OR use type="button"
- remove spaces in parameters

---

```
var w;
function openNotebook() {
  if (w && !w.closed) w.focus(); // focus if exists and is not closed
  else w = window.open("notebook.html","notebook",
    "width=800,height=600,resizable,top=50,left=10");

  return false; // or preventDefault or make the button type="button"
}
```

An alternative to testing if w.closed, remove the w from the opener by adding this in notebook.html

```
window.onbeforeunload=function() { opener.w=null; }
```

Comment: Works perfect thanks.  I was so close yet so far away!  :)

Comment: I have discovered a hiccup with this solution.

It works great but now when I close notebook.html (clicking a close button) and try to reopen, it won't as it thinks it is still open and goes into w.focus();



        function closeNotebook() {
         window.open('','_self').close();
         }  

Any further help much appreciated.

Comment: Excellent thanks :)  I went with the second option changing the js.  Works as expected.  Thanks for updating the answer for me much appreciated.